# ComponentNotRegisteredException when trying to resolve from a Fake IContainer

Tags: autofac, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to test out a part of my program that resolves instances of types.  To do this I created a fake IContainer:

```
this.container = A.Fake<IContainer>();
```

However, when I reach this line of code:

```
container.Resolve<APresenter>();
```

It's throwing a ComponentNotRegisteredException!

How does the fake IContainer know to even throw that exception?  The fake container should simply be a fake of the interface, not of the implementation.  What's going on here?

Comment: I think I found the issue.  Resolve is an extension method on the interface, not defined in the interface.

Comment: Good catch. You should make this an answer so you can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out IContainer.Resolve is an extension method of IContainer.  It's not defined in the interface.  I tried doing a whole bunch of setup on my Fake IContainer to get the extension method to work, but gave up after about an hour.

The far easier way was to create a `Resolver` interface and a wrapper around an Autofac `IContainer`.